# When running ads on facebook for a web app, does using the facebook sdk help in any way?

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-ads

I am new to the Facebook SDK for JavaScript and facebook ads. I am wondering what benefits the FB sdk has as opposed to calling the apis directly using fetch/axios. In particular I am wondering, when running ads on Facebook for a web app, does using the Facebook sdk help in any way?